# Why does Encode::decode with non-latin letter locales blow up on localised strftime output?

Tags: perl, utf-8, locale

On Ubuntu with Perl 5.26.1 I have encountered the following problem when working on Dancer::Logger::Console. I've lifted this code out of [Dancer2::Core::Role::Logger](https://metacpan.org/source/Dancer2::Core::Role::Logger#L100).

In order to run this, you need to generate the following locales:

```
sudo locale-gen de_DE.UTF-8
sudo locale-gen ko_KR.UTF-8
```

This example code uses the Korean locale, and fails without an error message. `$@` is empty.

```
$ LC_ALL=ko_KR.UTF-8 perl -MPOSIX -MEncode -E 'eval {
    say Encode::decode("UTF-8", strftime("%b", localtime))
  }; 
  say $@;
  '
Wide character at -e line 1.
```

When run with a German locale, it succeeds (but throws a wide character warning, which we can ignore for this test).

```
$ LC_ALL=de_DE.UTF-8 perl -MPOSIX -MEncode -E 'eval {
    say Encode::decode("UTF-8", strftime("%b", localtime))
  }; 
  say $@;
  '
Wide character in say at -e line 2.
M�r
```

The `%b` formatting is the abbreviated month as localised word (see http://strftime.net/).

If we don't `Encode::decode("UTF-8", ...)`, it works, and the version above with Korean produces `3월`.

What's going on here?

Comment: I've submitted a fix for the Dancer2 issue at https://github.com/PerlDancer/Dancer2/pull/1499.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Under `ko_KR.UTF-8`, `strftime("%b", localtime(1552997524))` returns `20.33.C6D4`. When interpreted as Unicode Code Points, this is "␠3월" ("March", with a leading space).

Under `de_DE.UTF-8`, `strftime("%b", localtime(1552997524))` returns `4D.E4.72`. When interpreted as Unicode Code Points, this is "Mär" (short form of "März", "March").

So it seems decoded text (Unicode Code Points) are being returned, which is perfect. All that's left to do is to *encode* the outputs.

```
$ LC_ALL=ko_KR.UTF-8 perl -CSD -MPOSIX -e'CORE::say strftime("%b", localtime)'
 3월

$ LC_ALL=de_DE.UTF-8 perl -CSD -MPOSIX -e'CORE::say strftime("%b", localtime)'
Mär
```

In a program (as opposed to a one-liner), you could use something like the following instead of `-CSD`:

```
use open ':std', ':encoding(UTF-8)';
```

Comment: Tip: I used `sprintf "%vX"` to examine the characters of the string. Data::Dumper with `Useqq = 1` would also do the trick.

Comment: I think I am missing something else though. I know I can get rid of the warning as you've described. In the Dancer2 source, it does `Encode::decode()`. I've linked to the relevant source above. I can't find anything else that happens with the string afterwards though. What I wonder is, why does it fail if it does Korean or Russian or Hebrew, and why is there no error message in `$@`.

Comment: It failed because you tried to decode already-decoded text, and because you didn't encode your outputs. /// `decode` doesn't throw exceptions on error by default. The third parameter of `decode` can be used to change that behaviour.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. Thanks. So basically the code in the Dancer2 file is buggy? I've spotted that the handler for `%T` in the logger format (again, see link above) doesn't `Encode::decode`, while `%t` does. If I drop the decoding the error goes away.

Comment: I have very little experience with locales, so I'll just limit my answer to the following: Make sure to test with locales that aren't based on UTF-8 before making any changes.

Comment: Nice, I didn't know about `-C` flag. If anyone else is wondering, see [perlrun](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html): "The -C flag controls some of the Perl Unicode features.", and then "S" = stdin/out/err utf8, "D" = in/out streams utf8, "A" = @ARGV utf8.

Comment: If you want to edit that in to make it consistent with the German translation, the Korean string says " 3 month". There are no month names in Korean. April is " 4 month".

Comment: I shall decline. That's like saying the English translation of "raton laveur" is "washing rat pup" instead of "raccoon".

Comment: @simbabque I would say it is definitely a bug to try to decode the output of strftime. || In case it's useful, I made an Encode wrapper with hopefully more sensible functions that you can choose between throwing exceptions and replacement characters (at least, you can look at its source to see how to do this correctly): [Encode::Simple](https://metacpan.org/pod/Encode::Simple)

Comment: @Grinnz, Keep in mind that Perl's handling of UTF-8 locales was super broken until recently. (5.20?) Maybe it's a bug now, but it wasn't before. So let me refine my earlier comment: Also test on older versions of Perl.